# LINQPad Reference "special" directories other than RuntimeDirectory

Tags: linqpad

In my "My Extensions" file I want to reference some assemblies with relative paths (either relative to the directory of LINQPad.exe or the MyExtensions file - whichever works). Currently I've used ".." paths and they seems to be relative to the current working directory, which is the LINQPad.exe directory if I start the EXE by double-clicking on it, but can be different if I double-clik a .linq file, for example.

I noticed that there is a  placeholder for framework assembly paths. Are there any other placeholders like this, which could be useful?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No. There doesn't appear to be a way.

Comment: That sucks... Thanks though.